# Get a link to just send a POST request but not actually go to a page

Tags: javascript, html, post

I am making a shopping list program and to increase the quantity of an item using a link but have the link send the POST request but not actually go to a page.
I'm not sure if this can be done.
This is what I am trying to do:

```
<a href="/view/{{row['item_category_id']}}/edit/{{row['item_id']}}/minus" style="float: left; margin-left: 2%;">-</a>
{{row["item_name"]}}
<kbd style="box-shadow: 0px 2px #d3d3d3;">[ {{row["item_quantity"]}} ]</kbd>
<a href="/view/{{row['item_category_id']}}/edit/{{row['item_id']}}/add" style="float: right; margin-right: 2%;">+</a>
```

I want the links to send a POST request without sending you to another page, this is so that the page wouldn't have to load each time you increased that value of an item.

Comment: you need ajax to send http request without reloading the page. See jQuery Ajax since it will be more easier for you than js native ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe preventDefault() method on event object would do the job, since i guess it is on click event, you can set link/button not to.. behave defaulty, and stay on same page.

```
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
});
```